# addClass with jQuery not working on scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll, sticky

I don't know what is going wrong with my code. I am using bootstrap 3 and I want to add a class to my `<nav>` when the user scroll to the bottom of the page, and remove this class when he scrolls back to the top.

It is very very weird, the jQuery is working normally (I put a code to hide the `<h1>` element for testing. However, the scroll function it is not working. That is very weird and frustrating because the exact same code works in other project, when using bootstrap 4 (I need to use the BS3 this time).

Could someone see what am I doing wrong? Is there anything on Bootstrap that prevent the addClass when scroll ?

Here's the Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
      $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").click(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.site-container {
  /*max-width:1920px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.marged-left-only {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}


/* changing active page (navbar menu) style */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #ed1c24;
}

.navbar {
  background-image: url("../images/radial-gradient-nav.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* reseting negative margin-left (-15px) default on bootstrap */

.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

main p {
  font-size: 2em;
  max-width: 300px;
  line-height: 2.2em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    /* (80px - line-height of 27px) / 2 = 26.5px */
    padding-top: 26.5px;
    padding-bottom: 26.5px;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-fluid {
    margin-right: 90px;
    margin-left: 90px;
  }
  .navbar {
    min-height: 160px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    height: 160px;
    line-height: 160px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    /* (80px - line-height of 27px) / 2 = 26.5px */
    padding-top: 53px;
    padding-bottom: 53px;
    line-height: 53px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  .container-fluid {
    margin: 0px 120px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1700px) {
  .container-fluid {
    margin: 0px 220px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>TESTE sticky</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>


  <!-- NAVBAR AREA -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- navbar-collapse -->
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li><a href="#">nous joindre</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <main>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam sint magni ratione delectus, id laborum ex aut non eius, reiciendis quae beatae at fuga cum dolores dicta nihil! Culpa, totam!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, reiciendis dolore vitae qui laborum earum cumque ratione commodi! Sit voluptate, esse sunt. Alias in officiis, qui fugit, omnis illum sequi.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, reiciendis dolore vitae qui laborum earum cumque ratione commodi! Sit voluptate, esse sunt. Alias in officiis, qui fugit, omnis illum sequi.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, reiciendis dolore vitae qui laborum earum cumque ratione commodi! Sit voluptate, esse sunt. Alias in officiis, qui fugit, omnis illum sequi.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, reiciendis dolore vitae qui laborum earum cumque ratione commodi! Sit voluptate, esse sunt. Alias in officiis, qui fugit, omnis illum sequi.</p>
  </main>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It won't cause a problem, but you don't need to use `document.ready` inside `document.ready`.

Comment: good point, I am going to delete one of those. Im just too tired hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The overflow hidden applied to my html element on the very top of my CSS is apparently preventing the scroll event to be listened.